# Registration form in buddypress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am new in buddypress. Is there any preloaded registration form in buddypress. If There is please give the option path. I used the plugin "BuddyPress Registration Options". But when i installed the plugin it displayed a error message like

```
    Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /var/www/TantraProjects/Ranjit/Nettantra_Social/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bp-registration-options/includes/admin.php on line 19 and defined in /var/www/TantraProjects/Ranjit/Nettantra_Social/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 990

    Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/TantraProjects/Ranjit/Nettantra_Social/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php:990) in /var/www/TantraProjects/Ranjit/Nettantra_Social/wordpress/wp-includes/option.php on line 568

    Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/TantraProjects/Ranjit/Nettantra_Social/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php:990) in /var/www/TantraProjects/Ranjit/Nettantra_Social/wordpress/wp-includes/o

ption.php on line 569
```

How can i build a registration form in buddypress.

Answer (score 0):

See this was asked a while ago, but I'll answer for documentation purposes. Yes there is a preloaded registration form. BuddyPress is mainly a wrapper on top of the WordPress registration (i.e. the About Me by default)

Path is /your-theme/buddypress/members/register.php

To build a custom registration form you can use this, place inside functions.php of your theme:

```
    <?php
// hacks and mods will go here
/**
 * Disables BuddyPress' registration process and fallsback to WordPress' one.
 */
function my_disable_bp_registration() {
  remove_action( 'bp_init',    'bp_core_wpsignup_redirect' );
  remove_action( 'bp_screens', 'bp_core_screen_signup' );
}
add_action( 'bp_loaded', 'my_disable_bp_registration' );

add_filter( 'bp_get_signup_page', "firmasite_redirect_bp_signup_page");
    function firmasite_redirect_bp_signup_page($page ){
        return bp_get_root_domain() . '/wp-signup.php'; 
    }
?>
```